# Wrong formatting datetime sas

Tags: datetime, sas

I want the system output to be: 14FEB18:11:53:49. I'm applying the format: datetime. But the output is 01JAN60:05:53:49.

```
data test;
date = today();
format date datetime.;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  below. Your applying datetime format to date and hence your getting wrong result. In sas if you see anything with 1960 as year most of the time, it because you are reading data wrongly or make a wrong calculation on date. Today() gives current date whereas datetime() gives current datetime.

```
data test;
date = datetime();
format date datetime.;
run;
```

Comment: It's worth noting the exact difference.  Dates are measured in days from 1/1/1960 and Datetime is measured in seconds from 1/1/1960:00:00:00.  So applying a datetime format to a date value will give you something in the year of 1960 (usually).